# Best way to subscribe to true value changes of FormControl in Angular2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, rxjs6

`valueChanges` Observable which exists on FormControl object emits value each time `setValue(value)` function gets called on FormControl object.

Using RxJS operator `distinctUntilChanged` we can filter out values which aren't new. But this doesn't work if FormControl has initial value.

```
const formGroup1 = new FormGroup({page: new FormControl(1)});
const formControl1 = formGroup1.get('page');
formControl1.valueChanges.pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(v => console.log(`new formControl1 value: ${v}`));
formControl1.setValue(1);
formControl1.setValue(2);
```

this is going to log

```
> new form1Control value: 1
> new form1Control value: 2
```

1 is the first value `valueChanges` Observable emits, because formControl1 value was set before `valueChanges` Observable was created.

`distinctUntilChanged` never filters out first emitted value

Here is one solution to this problem:

```
const formGroup2 = new FormGroup({page: new FormControl(1)});
const formControl2 = formGroup2.get('page');
formControl2.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(1),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    skip(1)
).subscribe(v => console.log(`new formControl2 value: ${v}`));
formControl2.setValue(1);
formControl2.setValue(2);
```

Here I'm modifying `valueChanges` Observable by emitting FormControl initial value, and then skipping it. So the first time `distinctUntilChanged` gets called, which is line:

`formControl2.setValue(1)`

it will already have previousValue (1) to compare new value to, so function inside subscribe won't get executed.

But I don't really like this solution. Is there built-in or recommended way to deal with FormControl value changes in Angular7 and RxJS6?

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arevmw?file=app%2Ficon-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly, you want your observable to only trigger on any value change except the initial value?

Have you tried setting the value when creating the form control

`new FormControl({ value: 1 });`

or you can specify that you don't want to emit an event when setting the value

`const formControl1  =new FormControl(1);
 formControl1.setValue(1, { emitEvent: false });`

According to the doc you can specify options when you set the value, including:

> emitEvent: When true or not supplied (the default), both the statusChanges and valueChanges observables emit events with the latest status and value when the control value is updated. When false, no events are emitted.

I hope this helps!

Comment: In my example, form control has initial value 1. I call setValue(1) right after creating the control, valueChanges observable emits 1, and I don't want that, because it's not a new value, it's the same as the initial one.

Comment: I think I understand you. I don't know of a build-in or recommended approach to intial form values and subscribing to their changes. Personally when I have to implement such an approach I end up with the emitEvent: false approach, but that's mostly a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

distinctUntilChanged initial state is always empty. But when first value is emitted distinctuntilchanged stored first value. After then second value is emitted it is compare new value and stored value. So your solution is correct or you can use skipWhile for your first value comparing.